# Accessing meta fields in script_fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I want some meta field in elasticsearch script_fields query,

I have tried following two ways but both failed.

**First Method:**

```
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "script_fields": {
      "FIELD_NAME": {
         "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": "params._routing"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Second Method:**

```
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "script_fields": {
      "FIELD_NAME": {
         "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": "params['_routing']"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Is there any way to access meta fields i.e. "_routing", "_parent" ?

Comment: I think It is not possible to reach meta fields of the document in the script.